# Как выбрать записи из таблицы, если их не существует (нужно выбрать товары, у которых какое-либо свойство не заполнено)?

Tags: mysql

Есть три таблицы:

```
options
product_options
products
```

В таблице options есть поля:

```
id, key, name
```

В таблице product_options есть поля:

```
product_id, key, value
```

В таблице products есть поля:

```
id, name, image, url
```

Мне нужно выбрать все товары, у которых не заполнено свойство manufacturer (Производитель).
Проблема в том, что если оно не заполнено, то в таблице просто нет записи.
А если нет записи, то как мне выбрать товары?

Я попытался помудрить с LEFT JOIN, но не получилось. Ничего не возвращается.
Вот мой код:

```
SELECT po.value as value, o.name as name
FROM  options o
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON (po.key = o.key)
LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.id = po.product_id)
WHERE po.value IS NULL
AND po.key = 'manufacturer'
```

Comment: Задай default как null для полей если можешь. Выбирай select where ... = NULL OR ... = NULL OR..... Или можешь выбивать как WHERE po.value = ''. Крч тебе надо подключиться к базе и глянуть чему у тебя там нулл равен в идеале.

Comment: *Мне нужно выбрать все товары, у которых* Написанное `SELECT po.value as value, o.name as name` как-то фигово соотносится со словом "товары".